Asking Multiple Questions


I have a question about my Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange post: Cognitive Dissonance: Reduction strategies, compartmentalization, and confirmation bias
Related: Asking a series of questions
I am unclear on the policies for asking multiple questions. Nothing seems to be said about it on How do I ask a good question?, though it is touched on in What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?:

Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Clearly, I made this mistake in my post since the 4 questions I asked were more or less independent, but I'd vaguely recalled seeing posts (on other StackExchanges) that contained multiple questions within them. Could someone point me to what the exact guidelines are for asking multiple questions? For instance, in my case, I didn't want to spam the front page with a lot of posts, but I have no idea of the etiquette around here.

Pinpoint the key point where you are stuck and ask that as a singular question in a post. Although you are allowed to ask four separate questions at once, following up on one should take you sufficient amount of time and you might in fact learn something from your initial questions which would help you asking better follow-up questions, rather than asking 5 questions at once.

If you are asking an expert, they might be prepared to give you an entire lecture on a very narrow topic. That is one of the reasons I think people shy away from multiple questions. It would just take too much time and effort to answer all of it - because it is just as interesting to the person answering.
